# Simple keyboardless touchscreen widgets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qml, qtquick2

I'm looking for a simple way to make widgets for a touch-screen that will allow users to set the time and IP address on the computer running the code and provide a simple (uppercase Latin-alphabetic) name.

This question is *not* about how to actually set the system time or IP address; I'm just looking for information about how to make the graphical widgets themselves.

What I want is for each editable property (time, address, and name) to be divided into "scrollable" fields, where the fields for "time" are hours, minutes, possibly seconds, and AM/PM/24-hr, and the fields for address/name are the individual characters. Each field would have an arrow above and below it, and touching on an arrow would scroll through the valid values for that field.

I think this is a pretty common UX pattern, especially in meatspace (e.g. on alarm clocks), but just in case it's not clear what I'm trying to describe, here's an example with a user editing the "name" property:

```
^^^
BN
vvv
```

User presses "down" below the "N":
    ^^^
    BO
    vvv

User presses "down" below the empty space:

```
^^^^
BOA
vvvv
```

...and again on the same down-arrow:

```
^^^^
BOB
vvvv
```

I'm writing this using C++14 with Qt 5. (If worst comes to worst, I'd be open to writing a separate app using a different language and/or framework, but I'm not asking for framework suggestions here; if you have one, let me know and I'll open a corresponding question on Software Recommendations SE.)

I don't see anything in the Qt 5 widget library like this; most of the input widgets are text fields. `QSpinBox` looks somewhat promising, but the arrows are probably too small for my touchscreen, and using a separate spinbox for each letter would probably be confusing and ugly.

I don't really know enough about Qt or GUI-programming in general to feel confident trying to write my own widgets from scratch, but this interface looks simple enough that I would expect a couple lines of QML would get me well on my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` as well as `PathView` can produce the desired result with slightly different behaviors and slightly different performances. Differently from `ListView`, `PathView` is circular, i.e. elements can be iterated continuously by using just one of the selection controls. It is also easier to fully customize the behavior of the path in `PathView` via the `PathAttribute` type. Anyhow path customization seems not to be a required feature, according to the question.

If you implement the solution via a `ListView` you should ensure that just one element is shown and that any model is processed.

```
Component {
    id: spinnnnnnnner

    Column  {
        width: 100
        height: 110
        property alias model: list.model
        property string textRole: ''
        spacing: 10

        Item {
            width: 100
            height: 25
            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: "-"; font.pixelSize: 25; font.bold: true }
            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: list.decrementCurrentIndex() }
        }

        ListView {
            id: list
            clip: true
            width: 100
            height: 55
            enabled: false          // <--- remove to activate mouse/touch grab
            highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange   // <--- ensures that ListView shows current item

            delegate: Text {
                width: ListView.view.width
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.pixelSize: 50
                font.bold: true
                text: textRole === "" ? modelData :
                                        ((list.model.constructor === Array ? modelData[textRole] : model[textRole]) || "")
            }
        }

        Item {
            width: 100
            height: 25
            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: "+"; font.pixelSize: 25; font.bold: true }
            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: list.incrementCurrentIndex() }
        }
    }
}
```

The checks over the model ensure that any type of model can be passed to the component. Here is an example using three very different models:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    width: 400
    height: 300

    ListModel {
        id: mod
        ListElement {texty: "it1"}
        ListElement {texty: "it2"}
        ListElement {texty: "it3"}
    }

    Row {
        Repeater {
            id: rep
            model: 3
            delegate: spinnnnnnnner

            Component.onCompleted: {
                rep.itemAt(0).model = mod                       // listmodel
                rep.itemAt(0).textRole = "texty"
                rep.itemAt(1).model = 10                        // number model
                //
                rep.itemAt(2).model = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]     // array model
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`PathView` implementation is not so different from the `ListView` one. In this case it is sufficient to define a vertical `path` and specify that just one one element is visible at a time via `pathItemCount`. Finally, setting `preferredHighlightBegin`/`preferredHighlightEnd` ensures that the visible element is centered in the view. The revisited component is the following:

```
Component {
    id: spinnnnnnnner

    Column  {
        width: 100
        height: 110
        property alias model: list.model
        property string textRole: ''
        spacing: 10

        Item {
            width: 100
            height: 25
            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: "-"; font.pixelSize: 25; font.bold: true }
            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: list.decrementCurrentIndex() }
        }

        PathView {
            id: list
            clip: true
            width: 100
            height: 55
            enabled: false          // <--- remove to activate mouse/touch grab
            pathItemCount: 1
            preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5
            preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5

            path: Path {
                startX: list.width / 2; startY: 0
                PathLine { x: list.width / 2; y: list.height  }
            }

            delegate: Text {
                width: PathView.view.width
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                font.pixelSize: 50
                font.bold: true
                text: textRole === "" ? modelData :
                                        ((list.model.constructor === Array ? modelData[textRole] : model[textRole]) || "")
            }
        }

        Item {
            width: 100
            height: 25
            Text { anchors.centerIn: parent; text: "+"; font.pixelSize: 25; font.bold: true }
            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: list.incrementCurrentIndex() }
        }
    }
}
```